# How to incrase counter value when both textbox value are equal in onClick using C#

Tags: c#, counter

How to incrase counter value when both textbox value are equal in onClick using  C#, I am trying but after click the value is only one.

Comment: Explain your question better please.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please understand that this is not a "how do I do that" answering website. You shall try something first, show your code, and tell us where or how it fails to work as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to something like this?

```
int counter = 0;

//in event

if(textbox1.ToString().Equals(textbox2.ToString()))
{
counter++;
}
```

Comment: You shall rather use the String .Equals(String) method instead of ==.

Comment: int counter = 0;

//in event

if(textbox1.ToString().Equals(textbox2.ToString()))
{
counter++;
textbox3.text = Convert.ToInt32(counter).ToString();
} /// but after click again it is not increasing

Answer (score 0):

store the value in your `UserControl` or `Window` like `int counter = 0;`. Then in `OnClick` Event compare the values and set `counter = counter + 1` which is the same as `counter++`